# Erroneously generated code in NetBeans for JFrames

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I'm doing a project in NetBeans that uses JFrames. To begin with, I had created the window in a package called "uam.pvoe.form" and among many other elements, I added a Combo Box called "cmbUnit". For the purpose of my submission, it is necessary that this Combo Box accepts objects of type "Unit" instead of "String" which is the default value for "Type parameters".

NOTE: In the image it says "Unidad" instead of "Unit" because the project is in Spanish but I am translating it for you.

[image: Combo Box properties]

The problem is that when I make this change, part of the code generated by NetBeans is not updated, specifically this part (that is where I get an error and it does not allow me to run the project):

[image]

I have made this kind of changes before but this has never happened to me. I think the problem is that the type of objects is no longer of type "String" and that array is invalid but as it is part of the automatically generated code, it does not allow me to modify it. To look for a solution, I checked other projects where I made similar changes in the "Type Parameters" but that line does not even appear in the generated NetBeans code. Could anyone help me on any possible steps I am skipping or any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Properties"-window you need to open the "Properties"-tab and delete the values of "model".